# Union All Transform: How to order the inputs

Tags: sql, ssis

I am using a union all transform to combine two input data sets. The first data set is a one column header and the second is one column of data. I want to use the union all transform to combine the header and data rows into one output column. I can't figure out how to make the header row appear first, before the data. No matter what I do, the header always comes last. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the query

```
select <columns> from header_table
union all
select <columns> from data_table;
```

Introduce an artifical column sort and use it in `ORDER BY`

```
select * from (
    select 0 as sort, <columns> from header_table
    union all
    select 1 as sort, <columns> from data_table) raw
order by sort;
```